# Guarantee that android keeps on retrieving sensor data

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler, android-wake-lock, android-fusedlocation, foreground-service

I'm developing an app that tracks trips. After searching about this matter, I concluded that the best way to achieve this (continuously track the user's location) is to use a foreground service. In some cases is working quite well, but in some other cases (even with DOZE off), I get some time intervals in which the phone is completely still and I stop getting sensor data (either accelerometer or locations from fused location provider).

This problem got worse when I tried it in an Android 9 device, (i guess) due to the new restrictions introduced by it (no sensor data when the phone is idle, etc.). To solve this issue, or at least try to reduce its effects, I thought about implementing a wakelock/job/alarm just to fire with a 1-minute frequency and do nothing. It might be a really bad idea but I´ve been struggling with this for a long time I dont know what to do anymore.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

From your post

> I get some time intervals in which the phone is completely still and I stop getting sensor data (either accelerometer or locations from fused location provider).

If the phone is still, why do you want to get any location or sensor data from tracking purposes?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Because it leads to "a one hour hole" in samples sometimes. There are some modes of transport in which the acceleration is really near 0 m/s.

Comment: I think what you need is a dedicated/purpose built device if you don't want to have any "holes" in the sample data. There are some tracking companies that provide real time location, normally come with a small dedicated device (running Android or some flavor of Linux I believe). If you absolutely have to get location data every minute, you can setup an alarm to wake-up the device. The drawback is you'll have a small icon (alarm clock) always displayed on notification bar & waking up a device every minute will also consume significant amount of battery.

Comment: Thank you very much again for the response! Will it consume a lot if it's just an alarm that wakes the CPU but does nothing? Do you have any recommendation on how to implement it?

Comment: My understanding is, waking up CPU by triggering an alarm would not only wake up CPU but also have all the radios e.g. wifi/data enabled as well. And when that happens, any app (not only your application) waiting for the network would also be awakened to do any pending IO. So definitely that will drain a significant amount of battery, and if you ask me I would definitely advise against waking up a device. Btw, What exactly are you doing with the location data?

Comment: The app is supposed to track all user's trips. I'm using the accelerometer with a 1s sampling frequency to acknowledge when the user has (probably) started to commute. When the app suspects that the user has moved (computing the average acceleration of the last 10-second interval), it turns on the fused location provider and starts gathering locations. If the user exits a 100-meter radius, we acknowledge that the user started a trip and therefore start saving those locations until the the end of the trip, which corresponds to the user stopping in a spot (or 100 meters around it) for 30minutes.

Comment: If it's a corporate or some fleet tracking app for tracking purposes, then it makes sense to setup an alarm to get the latest data sample at specific interval & the users might be ok with battery usage (the device might be plugged in always).

Answer (score 0):

Use a `WakeLock`. This is its intended purpose.

**EDIT**

To clarify: Your device most likely ceases collecting data because it is going to sleep. Under some circumstances, this behavior might be attributed to Doze, but you mentioned you are using a foreground service. According to a comment by Dianne Hackborn in [this post](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/94jCkmG4jff), apps with running foreground services are not restricted by Doze. And, according to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock), `WakeLocks` are an appropriate method of keeping the device awake.