# Thread-Sleep strange behavior

Tags: android, multithreading, service, sleep

i have build a simple Android App.
A Thread is collecting data, sleep 500ms, collecting and so on.
The app should do this endless (until I stop it).

Now the thread run in a foreground service (in the activity and in a background service android kill the thread/service after a couple minutes).

If some data collected, the thread save them in a text file.
(It collect 120 values in 1 minute, forms the mean and save this with timestamp).

When I am looking in the textfile, there data for 1-2 hours, every minute - like i want it.
But then absence data for 10 minutes, then for 30 minutes are data for every minute, then absence data for 2 hours and so on.

I can not figure out:
- if android sometimes not save the data,
- or is it to stupid to continuously sleep every 500ms (sometimes sleep 2 hours?),
- or android paused the hole service (randomly)
- ...

Is there a better way to collect data periodically?

Comment: Can you tell us more about how the data is collected ? Are you sure you need it to run it that often ?  
Did you consider scheduling periodic jobs ?

Comment: Actually it generates simply random 0/1 .

Comment: Later it should collect and save sensor data - at least every 10 seconds (as example magnetic field value)

Comment: Please check leonardkraemer's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49637967/minimal-android-foreground-service-killed-on-high-end-phone), he explains everything.

Comment: Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54354069/6759241)

Answer (score 0):

Android goes in the idle modus.

I solve the problem with a Partial Wakelock.